# Spark if there are good way to have 'maxRecordsPerFile' at load stage

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning

I have partitioned by spatial column (quadkey) data stored on s3. Let's say 5000 files in 150 partitions
When load into my spark application I want to break down that data into 15 000 partitions, but I want to preserve already existed partitioning. 
For example, generally I have 200 mb per partition now, so I want to break down those partitions down to 50 mb, and for partitions that I already have less than 50 mb I want to keep as it is. Of course there a lot of work arounds for this, but may be there some elegant solution like Spark has at saving stage:

```
preExportRdd.toDF
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile",maxCountInPartition)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save(exportUrl)
```

so I am wondering if there are something like

```
sqlContext.read.parquet(paths:_*)
  .option("maxRecordsFromFile",maxCountInPartition)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can preserve partitions in a sense that Spark recognizes it after load and save some shuffling when you join tables on the same partition keys. (For this to work you need Hive table, and potentially use bucketing)

However Spark has `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` which defaults to 128 Mb. It means if one file is more than this Spark would split it into multiple partitions after loading.

Spark might also merge multiple files on disks into one partition. You could try increasing `spark.default.parallelism` if you want to reduce the chance of partition merging.

Comment: is it really an answer?